# Swift Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: swift

Code:

```
if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path!) {
    let sourceSqliteURLs = [NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataDemo", withExtension: "sqlite")!, NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataDemo", withExtension: "sqlite-wal")!, NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataDemo", withExtension: "sqlite-shm")!]

    let destSqliteURLs = [self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite"),
        self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-wal"),
        self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-shm")]

    var error:NSError? = nil
    for var index = 0; index < sourceSqliteURLs.count; index++ {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(sourceSqliteURLs[index], toURL: destSqliteURLs[index])
        //showing error at this line             
    }
}
```

Compiler expecting `NSFileManager` inside try and catch block. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the `copyItemAtURL` function, you can do one of three things.

1) Try/catch

```
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager.copyItemAtURL(sourceSqliteURLs[index], toURL: destSqliteURLs[index])
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This is the standard error handling method. All your code would go inside the `do` block, including your `try` statement, and any errors would be handled in the `catch` block.

2) `try!`

```
try! NSFileManager.defaultManager()...
```

If an error is thrown with `try!` it will cause a runtime crash.

3) `try?`

```
 try? NSFileManager.defaultManager()...
```

Either the call will succeed or the result of the call will be nil. No errors thrown, no crash.

I would recommend you read the documentation, it's quite explicit about all this.

Comment: thanks..it is working fine